# Ruby on Rails User Login Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for user authentication.  I would like to create a component to be able to respond to a user logging in.  Does devise have user events or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the pages here: [Devise Wiki Pages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages). You can do things like redirect to certain pages. Additionally, when someone is logged in, so you can always check the `current_user` method provided by devise and see if it returns nil or a user.

Specifically look at redirecting on signin/signout. You can redirect to a controller action that does what you want.